# Applications restore or install from external sd card

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have Samsung Galaxy Duos Trans-S 7562. It had an problem with Wifi, so I sent the phone in for repairs. Before handing the phone over to store, I backed up the applications on the external Sd card.

Now applications can not be restored or installed. Only contacts are backed-up. The error message I get is `Applications not downloaded from Google Play store can not be installed.`

I used "Super backup-Contact And SMS" application for backing everything up.

Comment: Have you enabled `Settings > Security > Allow Unknown Sources`? That needs to be enabled to install non google play applications.

Comment: Yes,now it is working efficiently

Comment: Great, I'll add a full answer, it might help others!

Comment: Sure,I will pray from god to please you with some cookies today,you save me from dad's wrath

Comment: Cookies sound good :) Glad I helped, and you won't get in trouble. I have been there myself many times before and it is a horrible feeling! I'm off to buy cookies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that by default non [google-play](/questions/tagged/google-play) applications are blocked by default in Android, as a security measure.

To allow these to be installed go to (this may vary in wording across Android Versions)

`Settings > Security > Unknown Sources` this allows things to be installed that are not form the known (Google Play Store) source.

You can, in later versions, set only the inital install to process or allow any further ones to install.

In android it is similar to this (slight variety in different versions)
http://www.fannsoftware.com/img/UnknownSrc.png

On the Kindle it is slightly different:
[image]
<sub>(source: [bestvpn.com](https://www.bestvpn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Kindle-Fire.png))</sub>